# Problems with SASS @import in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have some trouble with SASS imports in rails 3.1. I've tried both the branch '3-1-stable' and the tag 'v3.1.0.rc4'.

**My Error**

```
Undefined variable: "$var1".
  (in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import "imp"; // defines $var1

body {
  border-right:5px solid $var1;
}
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/_imp.scss**

```
$var1: "blue";
```

Comment: try $var1: blue; in your _imp.scss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try renaming `_imp.scss` to `_imp.css.scss`?

Comment: Excellent, that did the job! Thanks!